# Gulp Concat files in order then any other js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

How would I go about adding some js files in a certain order then any other remaining ones? I was thinking of doing this:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./lib/file3.js', './lib/file1.js', './lib/file2.js', './lib/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Not sure if that would then re add already concated files since I am using a glob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gulp.src()` uses [`node-glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/glob.js) of `node-glob` the authors give a pseudo-code description of the algorithm (shortened, see source code for full pseudo-code):

```
// 1. Get the minimatch set
// 2. For each pattern in the set, PROCESS(pattern, false)
// 3. Store matches per-set, then uniq them
```

What this means for you is:

**Order is preserved.** The files `./lib/file3.js`, `./lib/file1.js` and `./lib/file2.js` will be emitted in that order if you explicitly pass them to `gulp.src()` in that order. No need to use `gulp-order` in that case.

**No duplicates.** Since the files are uniqed, none of them will be emitted twice in your gulp stream. In fact `node-glob` takes specific precautions to prevent duplicates for [brace expansion](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options):

> `nounique` In some cases, brace-expanded patterns can result in the same file showing up multiple times in the result set. By default, this implementation prevents duplicates in the result set. Set this flag to disable that behavior.

As well as for [symbolic links](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#comparisons-to-other-fnmatchglob-implementations):

> Note that symlinked directories are not crawled as part of a **, though their contents may match against subsequent portions of the pattern. This prevents infinite loops and duplicates and the like.

TLDR: Yeah, your code works.

Answer (score 2):

[Gulp-order](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order) might be what you're looking for. I haven't tested the following code, but the [docs](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order#usage) somewhat suggest that it will work. If it doesn't work, I'd suggest that you try to be more specific with the last globstar so that you're scoping to directories, if possible.

```
var order = require("gulp-order");

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./lib/**/*.js')
    .pipe(order([
      'file3.js', 
      'file1.js', 
      'file2.js', 
      '**/*.js'
     ]))
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

There's also an [article](https://martinwolf.org/blog/2014/08/force-a-concatenation-order-with-gulp-js) with a working example.